Splitting Columns into Multiple Columns based on Delimiters in R
I am working with the R programming language.
I have the following data frame:
start = data.frame(
var1 = c(1,2,3),
var2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
var3 = c( "text1, text2, text3", "text4", "text5, text6")
)

var1 var2                var3
    1    a text1, text2, text3
    2    b               text4
    3    c        text5, text6

My Question:  For var3, each time there is a comma, I am trying to break it up into new columns (and pad the empty positions with NULLS)
  var1 var2  col1  col2  col3
    1    a text1 text2 text3
    2    b text4  NULL  NULL
    3    c text5 text6  NULL

I tried this very lengthy way of doing this:
library(tidyr)
split_var3 <- strsplit(as.character(start$var3), ", ")

max_length <- max(sapply(split_var3, length))

new_columns <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split_var3, function(x) {
    length(x) <- max_length
    x
}))


new_columns <- as.data.frame(new_columns)
new_columns[is.na(new_columns)] <- "NULL"

end <- cbind(start[, 1:2], new_columns)

# rename 
colnames(end)[3:ncol(end)] <- paste0("col", 1:(ncol(end) - 2))

The code worked:
var1 var2  col1  col2  col3
    1    a text1 text2 text3
    2    b text4  NULL  NULL
    3    c text5 text6  NULL

Is there an easier way to do this?

You can try read.table like below
transform(
  start,
  var3 = read.table(
    text = var3,
    head = FALSE,
    sep = ",",
    fill = TRUE
  )
)

which gives
  var1 var2 var3.V1 var3.V2 var3.V3
1    1    a   text1   text2   text3
2    2    b   text4
3    3    c   text5   text6        


Or, you can use
with(
  start,
  cbind(
    start[-3],
    read.table(
      text = var3,
      head = FALSE,
      sep = ",",
      fill = TRUE
    )
  )
)

which gives
  var1 var2    V1     V2     V3
1    1    a text1  text2  text3
2    2    b text4
3    3    c text5  text6       


this ends up being a packed object. ie to access V1 you will have to do something like results$var3$V1. meaning you have a dataframe within a dataframe. Consider unpacking. In base R that would be using do.call

yes using cbind works too

If
cbind(start, `colnames<-`(Reduce(rbind, lapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l<-strsplit(start$var3, ","))))), paste0("col", 1:3)))

is not nice enough, do
start |> tidyr::separate_wider_delim(var3, delim =",", names=paste0("col", 1:3), too_few="align_start")


You could also use tstrsplit from data.table:
library(data.table)
setDT(start)[,c(.SD,tstrsplit(var3, ",")), .SDcols = -3]

    var1   var2     V3     V4     V5
   <num> <char> <char> <char> <char>
1:     1      a  text1  text2  text3
2:     2      b  text4   <NA>   <NA>
3:     3      c  text5  text6   <NA>

